# overheating problem with ubuntu, lubuntu and point mate in my netbook medion akoya e1222

Tags: overheating

Hello my name is Alex and I have a medion netbook a E1222 with a intel Atom N450 and 2gb of ddr2 ram and a intel Gma 3150 and when I installed ubuntu 10.04, 12.04, 13.04, lubuntu 13.04 and point linux mate it overheats to 78° c. I tried everything cleaning fans, installed mate, I installed google chrome and desinstalled firefox. I installed lubuntu the forums tell my that is a low resources OS but every time I have overheating problems. What can I do. I want to use linux i hate windows. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

78 C is not overheating. According to the Intel thermal [guidelines](http://download.intel.com/embedded/processors/thermalguide/323439.pdf) for the chip, 100 C is the maximum allowed temperature. If 78 C is the highest you are seeing, you are fine.

These netbooks are great, but have limitations. Low-power chips will generate heat, especially if you are doing a lot of intensive things that can add up: having lots of browser tabs open, downloading large files or a lot of small files in a row, watching a lot of YouTube videos in a row without a break, etc. Expect the temperature to go up when more tasks are given to the processor. Browser tabs in particular use way more resources than many people think.

I run several distros on a Lenovo S-10 with an N450 and 2 GB ram. Performance has been great with Unity through 12.10. Unity on 13.04 ran well enough, but was a little slow; so for 13.04 I use Lubuntu on that machine. My boot temperatures are in the low-60's, but going up to the 70's or even the 80's is normal. Try to close things and give the processor a break when that happens.